# Empty list exception while updating widget

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm Trying to pass data from firebase to widget, the data is shown in the debug but the application is crashing everytime I pass the parameters to the widget, here is the ERROR:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object
>   reference at
>   com.example.amrkamal.textme.MainActivity$4.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:224)
>   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown
>   Source:13) at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown
>   Source:2) at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown
>   Source:71) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

I decleared  `List<MessageModel> chatModelsArrayList;`

this is my code I write all of this in onCreate

```
chatModelsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
     chatModelsArrayList.clear();
            DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            databaseReference.child("messages").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        MessageModel usersModels = new MessageModel(
                                snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString(),
                                snapshot.child("text").getValue().toString());
                        chatModelsArrayList.add(usersModels); }
                    updateWidgetScreen(chatModelsArrayList);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.AddedTowidget, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
```

then this to update widget

```
private void updateWidgetScreen(List<MessageModel> chatModelsList) {
                String users = getString(R.string.messages_list_name);

                for (MessageModel user : chatModelsList) {

                    users = users
                            + user.getName() + ": "
                            + user.getText() + " \n";
                }
                WidgetUpdateService.startWidgetUpdate(this, users);
            }
```

what's the problem please ? any solution ?

[image: Debugging Screen]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the code is executed asynchronously. Have you tried adding a null check like this:

```
  @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    **if (snapshot != null)**
                    **{**
                    MessageModel usersModels = new MessageModel(
                            snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString(),
                            snapshot.child("text").getValue().toString());
                    chatModelsArrayList.add(usersModels); }
                updateWidgetScreen(chatModelsArrayList);
                    **}**
            }
```

Comment: Then maybe the DataSnapshot that is passed in to onDataChange() is null. Add a null check for it.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference messagesRef = rootRef.child("messages");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<MessageModel> chatModelsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            MessageModel messageModel = ds.getValue(MessageModel.class);
            chatModelsArrayList.add(messageModel );
            Log.d("TAG", messageModel.getName() + " / " + messageModel.getText());
        }

        //Call method to update widget
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
messagesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in the logcat will be:

```
Amr Kamal / fsafsfa
Amr Kamal / hii
//And so on
```